# How to bind the NSMutableArray to ArrayController through xib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I am new to Cocoa . I am displaying a simple Tableview populated with NSMutableArray which is bound to the NSArrayController as follows

```
[_arrController bind:@"contentArray" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"dataArray" options:nil];
```

Here _arrController is the IBoutlet to my NSArrayController and dataArray is my NSmutableArray with the data.

I am successful in populating the Tableview when I do the binding programatically. However I am not able to achieve the same binding through the Interface Builder.

I selected ArrayController in my IB , went to binding section,and tried binding under the controller section by selecting the model key path as  dataArray.But however , my table is not populated with data , where as programatically I can achieve my task easily. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a example which might help you to fix the issue.

1. iVar - > demoArray
2. IBOutlet -> demoArrayController

> @interface ExAppDelegate : NSObject
>
> @property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
>
> @property (strong) NSMutableArray *demoArray;
>
> @property (strong) IBOutlet NSArrayController *demoArrayController;
>
> @end

Below is the implementation of the same class

```
@implementation ExAppDelegate
@synthesize demoArray;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    self.demoArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=0 ; i <= 10 ; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [temp setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"number"];
        [temp setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Demo %d",i] forKey:@"demoKey"];
        [self.demoArray addObject:temp];        
    }
    [self.demoArrayController rearrangeObjects];
}

@end
```

Now, UI Bindings - >

1. Array Controller Bindings as show in below in the image

[image]

2. Table View Column bindings.

[image]

**NOTE:**

*1. Make sure you are calling the rearrangeObjects on Array Controller after you add the objects to an array which is binded to Array Controller.*

[self.demoArrayController rearrangeObjects];

*2. In Table View Column Bindings make sure you have checked the check box "Continuously Updates Value".*

I Hope this fix the issue.

Comment: `[self.demoArrayController rearrangeObjects]` seems to be the key if you are using a NSMutableArray rather than an NSArray.

Answer (score 1):

The steps are as follows (just in case you missed anything):

- Add the array controller
- Set the Mode of the array controller to Class and add the Class name.
- Add the Keys you want to bind

If you are using and View based table view. Do following:

- Click the column in your table view (often takes three clicks on the
  table view)
- Check Value in Bindings Inspector
- Controller Key: ArrangedObjects and your Model Key Path.
- Mark your Static Text in your table view cell.
- Bind your Static Text to Table Cell View and your Model Key Path.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I dint get how to do this Set the Mode of the array controller to Class and add the Class name.

Comment: After you've dragged in the Array controller. Click it in IB, then go to "Attributes inspector". You set it under the header "Object Controller"

Comment: Oh ok.. That I have done already . I got my mistake now. I was simply adding object to my NSmutableArray using [dataArray addoObject:book];Instead I should do it  [[self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"dataArray"] addObject:book2];

Comment: Thanks @Raj, confirmed. You should put mutableArrayValueForKey:addObject into a separate answer and accept it. It feels a bit strange to write and accept your own answer, but in this case it's the right thing to do.